# Cypress | Click on a button in a column inside a row on specific condition

Tags: jquery, html-table, cypress

I've a table that includes multiple rows and columns.

I want to trigger the following scenario:

- Get the row that has any of its columns match specific keywords.
- Click on a button inside this row.

Here is my table structure:

[image]

And here is my code snippet

```
clickOnDeleteIcon(email: string)  {
        cy.get('tbody.MuiTableBody-root tr td', { timeout: 20000})
            .filter(`:contains(${email})`)
            .parentsUntil('tbody.MuiTableBody-root tr')
            .find('button[title = "Delete"]')
            .click()
    }
```

I also tried

```
clickOnDeleteIcon(email: string)  {
        cy.contains('tbody.MuiTableBody-root tr td', email).parent('tr')
            .find('button[title = "Delete"]')
            .click()
    }
```

But, I'm getting timeout in filter

```
Timed out retrying after 10000ms: Expected to find element: :contains(Julie_Williamson88@gmail.com), but never found it. Queried from element: [ <td.MuiTableCell-root.MuiTableCell-body.MuiTableCell-paddingNone>, 1535 more... ]
```

Comment: You need to delete all the emails or a specific email ?

Comment: @AlapanDas Specific email, the one I pass to the function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
cy.get('tbody.MuiTableBody-root tr', {
  timeout: 15000,
})
  .should('be.visible')
  .each(($ele, index) => {
    if ($ele.text().toLowerCase().trim().includes('ursula_white@gmail.com')) {
      cy.wrap($ele).within(() => {
        cy.get('[title="Delete"]').click()
      })
    }
  })
```

Comment: @Alan 

When I use `cy.get('tbody.MuiTableBody-root tr')`, the matched results aren't retrieved. 

I just tried this and the cy.log isn't executed as well.

```
clickOnDeleteIcon(email: string)  {
        cy.get('tbody.MuiTableBody-root tr').each(($ele) => {
            cy.wrap($ele).within(() => {
                if ($ele.text().includes(email)) {
                    cy.log('eh da ba2a')
                    cy.get('button[title="Delete"]').click()
                }
            })
        })
    }
```

Comment: I want to access the parent of `$ele` in the if statement?

Comment: Added an assertion. basically now instead of `td` we are looping through `tr` and getting the entire inner text of the row. Now if the row has the email, we scope our search to that row using `within` and then click the delete button. Updated the answer. can you try. Also changed the position of the if statement.

Comment: Same thing, the code inside this condition isn't executed `$ele.text().includes(email)`

Comment: please post the error screenshot. upload it to imgur and add in the comments. And also please hardcode the email for now and try instead of using the parameter.

Comment: Here you go https://imgur.com/a/W0u95s8

Comment: Let's debug this. Can you execute this? This should print 1 to 251. I want to check if `.each` is working or not. `cy.get('tbody.MuiTableBody-root tr', {
  timeout: 15000,
})
  .should('be.visible')
  .each(($ele, index) => {
    cy.log(index)
  })`

Comment: I executed this
```clickOnDeleteIcon(email: string)  {
        cy.get('tbody.MuiTableBody-root tr', {
            timeout: 15000,
        })
            .should('be.visible')
            .each(($ele, index) => {
                cy.log(index.toString())
                if ($ele.text().includes(email)) {
                    cy.log('email found')
                    cy.wrap($ele).within(() => {
                        cy.get('button[title="Delete"]').click()
                    })
                }
            })
    }```

Comment: The logs inside `.each` are working while the one inside the if condition isn't

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238283/discussion-between-alapan-das-and-mona101ma).

Answer (score 1):

the `filter()` command uses css, but `:contains` does not seem to be valid css as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text).

You should use [`contains()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains) command from cypress to query elements by their text content.

I would use it like this:

```
cy.get('tbody.MuitableBody-root')
    .contains('tr', email)
    .find('button[title="Delete"]')
    .click();
```

Comment: It cause a timeout as well.